# Pasting from a variable defined range

Tags: variables, excel-indirect, pasting

New to vba and I am having difficulties with pasting. Here is my code:

Dim xtext As String

Dim ytext As String

x = ActiveSheet.Range("A8")

y = ActiveSheet.Range("A9")

Range("A6").Select 
Selection.Copy

Range("xtext:ytext").Select 
Selection.Paste

Endsub

Cell A8 (which is variable x) value is B2, and Cell A9 (which is variable y) is B10. I thought it would paste from B2:B10 but instead is pasting into columns x:y. So I kind of want it to work like an indirect formula? I am not sure if this is even close to what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your variables - "x" & "y" are bad as they are not indicative of what they hold. This is particularly true in Excel, where a single letter also refers to a column - which is what has happened here; you have posted to the range "X:Y", which is just the selection of all of column X, and all of column Y.

Your whole code together becomes [note that I changed your definition of x and y to be ranges, not text strings, and as such had to make them equal to your A8 & A9 by "set = to"] [assuming in your spreadsheet that cell A8 says "B2", and A9 says "B10"]:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range

Set x = ActiveSheet.Range("A8")
Set y = ActiveSheet.Range("A9")


Range("A6").Select
Selection.Copy

Range(x.Text, y.Text).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

**Edited to now refer indirectly to what is entered into cells A8 & A9**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think I may have mislead you. The Range("A10") and Range("A11") were for verification purposes only. If I change my variables to xtext and ytext, what I want is to paste in their range, so now I have more simply:                                                                                     Dim xtext As String
Dim ytext As String
    
xtext = ActiveSheet.Range("A8")
ytext = ActiveSheet.Range("A9")                                                       Range("A6").Select Selection.Copy

Range("xtext:ytext").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Edit your question to provide your data and what you want your results to be.

Comment: Okay, I edited it. I just want to paste into the range that the variables are if that makes sense.

Comment: Check my edits. In the future, that sort of clarity is required. The more you say about what your data is and what you want to happen, the easier it is to resolve.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: If the answer does what you need, please click 'accept' next to it. Thanks